# How to extract Photoshop curve points to RGB number array?

Tags: image, photoshop

Hi I made some filter effects using Photoshop curves and they look like this:
[image]

[image]

Is there a way I can extract each one of the 256 numbers from each color so it is a number array like this?

```
var r = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 19, 19, 20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 52, 54, 55, 57, 59, 60, 62, 65, 67, 69, 70, 72, 74, 77, 79, 81, 83, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 97, 99, 101, 103, 107, 109, 111, 112, 116, 118, 120, 124, 126, 127, 129, 133, 135, 136, 140, 142, 143, 145, 149, 150, 152, 155, 157, 159, 162, 163, 165, 167, 170, 171, 173, 176, 177, 178, 180, 183, 184, 185, 188, 189, 190, 192, 194, 195, 196, 198, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 206, 207, 208, 209, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 218, 219, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 227, 228, 229, 229, 230, 231, 232, 232, 233, 234, 234, 235, 236, 236, 237, 238, 238, 239, 239, 240, 241, 241, 242, 242, 243, 244, 244, 245, 245, 245, 246, 247, 247, 248, 248, 249, 249, 249, 250, 251, 251, 252, 252, 252, 253, 254, 254, 254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
```

Sorry for the question if it's stupid, i'm not even sure what i'm asking, it's late.

**UPDATE:** following [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell)'s answer, i was able to create a saved.ppm file with these values inside it.

[image]

The last step was to extract the RGB values from this long string of numbers, Red is the 0th, 3nd, 6th number, Green is the 1st, 4th, 7th number etc.

For anyone else's interest, I was trying to create a filter on Photoshop curves, then extract its RGB values and apply it using pixel cross processing on HTML Canvas, similar to a demo shown [here](https://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-image-effects-sepia/).

Comment: Actually, there's an easier way. I'll make you a 256px by 1px image later of a greyscale starting at 0 and going to 255. You can then apply your curve and dump the result. The first pixel will show you what your curve does to black 0 pixels, the second will show you what it does to pixels with value 1 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a totally different, and simpler way of doing it. Save the data below in a file called `ramp.ppm` - it is a Portable Pixmap format from the NetPBM suite [see Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format). It is a black-to-white greyscale ramp 256 pixels wide and 1 pixel tall.

Load that into Photoshop and apply your curve to it then save as a PNG file.

```
P3
256 1
255
0 0 0
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
6 6 6
7 7 7
8 8 8
9 9 9
10 10 10
11 11 11
12 12 12
13 13 13
14 14 14
15 15 15
16 16 16
17 17 17
18 18 18
19 19 19
20 20 20
21 21 21
22 22 22
23 23 23
24 24 24
25 25 25
26 26 26
27 27 27
28 28 28
29 29 29
30 30 30
31 31 31
32 32 32
33 33 33
34 34 34
35 35 35
36 36 36
37 37 37
38 38 38
39 39 39
40 40 40
41 41 41
42 42 42
43 43 43
44 44 44
45 45 45
46 46 46
47 47 47
48 48 48
49 49 49
50 50 50
51 51 51
52 52 52
53 53 53
54 54 54
55 55 55
56 56 56
57 57 57
58 58 58
59 59 59
60 60 60
61 61 61
62 62 62
63 63 63
64 64 64
65 65 65
66 66 66
67 67 67
68 68 68
69 69 69
70 70 70
71 71 71
72 72 72
73 73 73
74 74 74
75 75 75
76 76 76
77 77 77
78 78 78
79 79 79
80 80 80
81 81 81
82 82 82
83 83 83
84 84 84
85 85 85
86 86 86
87 87 87
88 88 88
89 89 89
90 90 90
91 91 91
92 92 92
93 93 93
94 94 94
95 95 95
96 96 96
97 97 97
98 98 98
99 99 99
100 100 100
101 101 101
102 102 102
103 103 103
104 104 104
105 105 105
106 106 106
107 107 107
108 108 108
109 109 109
110 110 110
111 111 111
112 112 112
113 113 113
114 114 114
115 115 115
116 116 116
117 117 117
118 118 118
119 119 119
120 120 120
121 121 121
122 122 122
123 123 123
124 124 124
125 125 125
126 126 126
127 127 127
128 128 128
129 129 129
130 130 130
131 131 131
132 132 132
133 133 133
134 134 134
135 135 135
136 136 136
137 137 137
138 138 138
139 139 139
140 140 140
141 141 141
142 142 142
143 143 143
144 144 144
145 145 145
146 146 146
147 147 147
148 148 148
149 149 149
150 150 150
151 151 151
152 152 152
153 153 153
154 154 154
155 155 155
156 156 156
157 157 157
158 158 158
159 159 159
160 160 160
161 161 161
162 162 162
163 163 163
164 164 164
165 165 165
166 166 166
167 167 167
168 168 168
169 169 169
170 170 170
171 171 171
172 172 172
173 173 173
174 174 174
175 175 175
176 176 176
177 177 177
178 178 178
179 179 179
180 180 180
181 181 181
182 182 182
183 183 183
184 184 184
185 185 185
186 186 186
187 187 187
188 188 188
189 189 189
190 190 190
191 191 191
192 192 192
193 193 193
194 194 194
195 195 195
196 196 196
197 197 197
198 198 198
199 199 199
200 200 200
201 201 201
202 202 202
203 203 203
204 204 204
205 205 205
206 206 206
207 207 207
208 208 208
209 209 209
210 210 210
211 211 211
212 212 212
213 213 213
214 214 214
215 215 215
216 216 216
217 217 217
218 218 218
219 219 219
220 220 220
221 221 221
222 222 222
223 223 223
224 224 224
225 225 225
226 226 226
227 227 227
228 228 228
229 229 229
230 230 230
231 231 231
232 232 232
233 233 233
234 234 234
235 235 235
236 236 236
237 237 237
238 238 238
239 239 239
240 240 240
241 241 241
242 242 242
243 243 243
244 244 244
245 245 245
246 246 246
247 247 247
248 248 248
249 249 249
250 250 250
251 251 251
252 252 252
253 253 253
254 254 254
255 255 255
```

If you have Linux, and you have ImageMagick, you can then convert the saved `PNG` file back into a `PPM` file with

```
convert saved.png -compress none saved.ppm
```

The file `saved.ppm` will then show you the output of your curve for each input value in the greyscale ramp - in effect it will be the 256 values you are looking for.

If you don't have ImageMagick, just give me the PNG file and I'll convert it for you.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark! This is perfect!

Comment: Excellent - glad it worked for you. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel like writing the code today, least of all when you are not too sure what you are up to! However, what you are asking is perfectly achievable.

If you save the curve you have created (the `Save` option is in the top right menu), you will get a `.ACV` file. The format of this file is given [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/#50577411_pgfId-1056330) if you scroll down to the section entitled **Curves**. It is a pretty simple format with just an identifier and a version number then a count of the number of points that you have defined for your curve, i.e. 6 in your case. Then, for each point, the 4 coordinates. These can be pretty easily extracted with Perl or similar.

You could then fit a curve to those points, probably using GNUplot, and interpolate to find the points you are looking for.

Excerpt from referenced document:

[image]

Here is an extract from some code I wrote in Perl that actually writes a `.ACV` file. I know you will actually want to read one, bit you'll get the idea of the byte packing technique...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Image::Magick;
use Data::Dumper;

my $Debug=1;    # 1=print debug messages, 0=don't
my $NPOINTS=5;  # Number of points in curve we create

....
.... other stuff
....

# Work out name of the curve file = image basename + acv
my $curvefile=substr($imagename,0,rindex($imagename,'.')) . ".acv";
open(my $out,'>:raw',$curvefile) or die "Unable to open: $!";
print $out pack("s>",4); # Version=4
print $out pack("s>",4); # Number of curves in file = Master NULL curve + R + G + B

print $out pack("s>",2);                        # Master NULL curve with 2 points for all channels
print $out pack("s>",0  ),pack("s>",0  );       # 0 out, 0 in
print $out pack("s>",255),pack("s>",255);       # 255 out, 255 in

print $out pack("s>",2+$NPOINTS);               # Red curve
print $out pack("s>",0  ),pack("s>",0  );       # 0 out, 0 in
for($p=0;$p<$NPOINTS;$p++){
   print $out pack("s>",$Rpoint[$p]),pack("s>",$greypoint[$p]);
}
print $out pack("s>",255),pack("s>",255);       # 255 out, 255 in

print $out pack("s>",2+$NPOINTS);               # Green curve
print $out pack("s>",0  ),pack("s>",0  );       # 0 out, 0 in
for($p=0;$p<$NPOINTS;$p++){
   print $out pack("s>",$Gpoint[$p]),pack("s>",$greypoint[$p]);
}
print $out pack("s>",255),pack("s>",255);       # 255 out, 255 in

print $out pack("s>",2+$NPOINTS);               # Blue curve
print $out pack("s>",0  ),pack("s>",0  );        # 0 out, 0 in
for($p=0;$p<$NPOINTS;$p++){
   print $out pack("s>",$Bpoint[$p]),pack("s>",$greypoint[$p]);
}
print $out pack("s>",255),pack("s>",255);        # 255 out, 255 in

close($out);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer!!! Looked around Google for ages and just can't find a page where people done this before. I will certainly look into Perl and GNUplot now